# Cast a @param in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that takes a `@columnName` parameter, and I am using it in building the query:

```
AND @columnName LIKE '%' + @userInput + '%'
```

If I replace the `@columnName` with a static value it works, like this:

```
AND userName LIKE '%' + @userInput + '%'
```

I believe this is because the `@columnName` is treated as string, because when running the stored procedure, it is being passed as string like that:

```
 EXEC app.findUsers 'UserName', 'sa'
```

Is it possible to do it without using a dynamic query string?

Comment: You can't. If you want to use a variable for a column name you have to use dynamic SQL to build a string containing SQL which you then execute.

Comment: SQL just doesn't work this way, DDL cannot be dynamic at runtime, a query is parsed and an execution plan built at compile time - it's then static - any change is a new query.

Comment: Normally, if you have a requirement like this I find it an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: If you have a small set of columns you could do `WHERE (@col = 'foo' AND foo LIKE '%' + @userInput + '%') OR (@col = 'bar' AND bar LIKE '%' + @userInput + '%') ...` but that is going to horribly bad for performance since you'll get one plan for potentially several different indexes etc. Much better to use dynamic SQL, e.g. see https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql

Comment: See [this article series](https://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for a thorough treatment on how to do queries with dynamic search conditions without shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Stu Both DDL and DML can be dynamic in SQL Server.  Could you explain what you meant?

Comment: @BrianLeach I mean exactly what I say, DDL/DML can be *built* dynamically (I missed DML in earlier comment), but the compiled query definition can't *change* at runtime, ie, what the Op is expecting to do by varying the column name used in an expression by using a variable etc in an executing query.

Comment: If you want to query a dynamic column, you need dynamic SQL, @AliAlAmine .If that's a problem, it further cements my suggestion you probably have an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SQL Dynamic to do this.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE [' + @columnName + '] LIKE ''%' + @userInput  + '%'''
PRINT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Why not pass all the query updated into a dynamic query ?

Comment: Not exactly what I want, but the `PRINT` helped me figuring it out..

Comment: In which case your query becomes wide open to SQL injection attacks and you lose one of the biggest advantages of using parameters in the first place.